# ERD table design

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I'm developing a website and need to create an ERD for the website. I've never created one before but will be using MySQL to design it once I figure out the tables necessary. All I am asking for is for ideas on what tables might be necessary for this website. Here is a link to an image of the website:

[image: WISCON]!

Obviously there needs to be a user table. I have that created already with all pertinent info. Do I need to create a login, register, home, elite login, photos, events, newsletter, and contact us tables? The photo link will bring the user to a page where there are folders for each event, if you click on the folder it then opens up another page with the actual photos, but you need to be a registered user to view these. Is the login hyperlink going to be the user table? Would the register link be to another table or would that add to the user table? The events page is only going to be a list of hyperlinks that take you to a new page with dates and descriptions of the events, does this need it's own table? And lastly does the newsletter and contact us pages need separate tables as well?

Like I stated, I am not looking for anyone to help create the dERD but only to let me know if all these tables would be necessary. From there I can build the ERD and create the appropriate relationships and so forth.

Comment: Your link does not work. Use SO's image uploader.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably benefit from learning about MVC- Model, View, Controller systems.

Views (in a webapp) map pretty well to the HTML pages you display.

Models map pretty well to the "Nouns" in your system- these are the things in your database; Users, Photos, Newsletters are examples of things that go here.

Controllers map to the "Verbs" in your system- Register, Subscribe, Upload, Save, Login are all actions that a controller might provide.

Only the Model layer lives in the database in most frameworks.

I'd suggest that you think about your problem in a more holistic fashion, rather than diving into diagramming a bunch of unrelated ideas. ERD's really only map to the stuff you need to be persistent.

Comment: So, essentially all I need are the user, photos, events tables?

Comment: Not much of what you wrote made any sense to me. I've never worked with MVC's (obviously) and all I really got out of it is that the "nouns" might be what I use to create the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you first draw paper prototypes of most of the user interfaces, at least at a high level. Then do usability tests on those prototypes to make sure your interface designs make sense to someone other than you. (User Interface Design by Soren Lausen is a good book for that.)

Then, once you have a decent idea of how your interfaces are going to work, think of the models necessary to make those interfaces work. Obviously, a login form with a username and password will require a `User` entity with `username` and `password` (or, actually, `encrypted_password`) attributes. Getting all these models nailed down may take some skill that I sense you may not have yet, but this task will be much easier and clearer to you if you have your interfaces drawn out than if you're just trying to sit there and think about it. Your first pass will probably be wrong, but that's okay. Start with the smallest subset of the program that could be useful on its own, build that to the point where it's completely working, and then expand from there.

Good luck!

Comment: I did draw the tables I assumed were needed fro the ERD but it became way too complex and I realized I was not doing this properly. Therefor I came here for a bit of help. I'm going to start with just the user, photos, and events tables. If others are neeeded from there I will add them. This appeared easier on the surface that it has turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

After looking this over I have come to realize that I have jumped the gun quite a bit and need to do a lot more work on the design of the site before even thinking about the ERD. The client has only approved the mock up of the "home" page and the other pages have yet to be discussed at any length. Nothing is set in stone as it were. Therefor, creating an ERD is very premature. Many thing, from now until the database needs to be looked at, can change. 
Please excuse this topic as I was overly excited about my first project. I need to focus on the agile development process and slow down. Focus on the individual steps and let things develop from that.